# scrolling not working in ion-view

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. I am trying to get my ionic page design right, but I am facing scrolling related issue. Following is my index.html code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
                <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                    <button class="button button-icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
                <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                    <button class="button button-icon ion-search"></button>
                    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-email"></button>
                    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-person"></button>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
                <h1 class="title"> Main Nav bar</h1>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-balanced bar-subheader">
                <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left"></button>
                <button class="button">ABC</button>
                <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-footer-bar class="bar bar-footer bar-positive">
                Footer
            </ion-footer-bar>
            <ion-nav-view>
                <ion-view>
                    <ion-content>
                        <h1> Sub header example 1</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 2</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 3</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 4</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 5</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 6</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 7</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 8</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 9</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 10</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 11</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 12</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 13</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 14</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 15</h1>
                    </ion-content>
                </ion-view>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="item">first
            </ul>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
  </body>
</html>
```

It shows UI, where following are the problems :- 
1)  There's some gap, which is left, as highlighted in image given below :- [image]

2)  There's some content, which get hidden under footer, as shown in image given below :-
[image]

I don't know, what mistake I have made in using ion-content and ion-view.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
                <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                    <button class="button button-icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
                <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                    <button class="button button-icon ion-search"></button>
                    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-email"></button>
                    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-person"></button>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
                <h1 class="title"> Main Nav bar</h1>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-balanced bar-subheader">
                <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left"></button>
                <button class="button">ABC</button>
                <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
            </ion-header-bar>
                    <ion-content>
                        <h1> Sub header example 1</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 2</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 3</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 4</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 5</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 6</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 7</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 8</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 9</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 10</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 11</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 12</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 13</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 14</h1>
                        <h1> Sub header example 15</h1>
                    </ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar bar-footer bar-positive">
                Footer
            </ion-footer-bar>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="item">first
            </ul>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
  </body>
</html>
```

You may try with this slight change , this will work for u

Comment: Can you please explain the changes, that you have done ? Moreover, can you comment on, what I was missing or what wrong I have done ?

Comment: u just wrote footer above content !! footer must always be after content , moreover u used  <ion-nav-view>
                <ion-view> and there was no need of it , so i removed those

Comment: footer looks your content and prevents it from scrolling. so footer must always at the bottom @ManguSinghRajpurohit

Comment: Actually footer is not the problem, problem is about <ion-nav-view> and <ion-view>. Removing these two tags, without making any change in footer, make UI working. But why we need to remove <ion-nav-view> ? ionic docs says that it's required in any app, to keep track of navigation.

Comment: Have worked with few ionic apps, but without this, I am being navigating everywhere properly. U may try an application with navigation, without ion-nav-view